# How to make Listbox.List keep type information?

Tags: vba, listbox-control

If I affect a full array to a ListBox, using `ListBox1.List = [{1;2;3;4}]` for example, the Listbox's `.List` items keep their correct type (here numbers), but if I use `ListBox1.AddItem 5` or `Listbox1.List(5) = 6` to set an individual item the type is automatically changed to `String`.

**Sample Code:**

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ListBox1.List = [{1;2;3;4}]
    ListBox1.AddItem 5
    ListBox1.AddItem
    ListBox1.List(5) = 6
End Sub
```

[image]

Later on, when comparing values, I get wrong results because numbers are not equals to text (`5 <>"5"`).

Is there any easy (1) way to ensure the type of the list items is not converted to `String`?

(1) I know I can explicitly make the conversion to String, but I rather keep my values as numbers instead of "numbers-strored-as-text" in the listbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that will be impossible when using `AddItem`. According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.listbox.additem, the first parameter is a string, so everything you pass will be converted to a string.

Probably your best bet is to collect all items in an array and assign the array using `ListBox1.List`. Or you have to live with numbers stored as string...

**Update**
I mixed the pages up - link to the Access page was wrong.
Anyhow, Documentation is rather poor. It says *"valid object"* but doesn't define what that means. At least it is not possible to add a `object` - that throws a type mismatch.

Also, the documentation states that a `Variant` is returned, but it seems thatis not true - when I try to get the result, the compiler throws an error.

As a conclusion, I assume that `AddItem` converts everything to a string (and throws an error if that fails). So I still assume that you have to build up an array and assign it to `List` if you want to have real numbers.

Comment: Well, I'm not using the Access Listbox control, but the MSForm one, and [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/additem-method) does not specify "String"